# Get the raw decrypted filesystem image out from a dm_crypt image file without dm_crypt kernel module and/or root permissions

Tags: linux, filesystems, dm-crypt

On my linux box I have a small encrypted file system in an image file, like the following example. This works fine.

```
# Create encrypted filesystem image file
dd if=/dev/zero of=fs.img bs=1M count=100
cryptsetup -yvh sha256 -c aes-xts-plain -s 256 luksFormat fs.img
# Mount the encryptes fs image file
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen fs.img cfs
sudo mkfs.ext2 /dev/mapper/cfs
sudo mount /dev/mapper/cfs mnt/
# Unmount and close fs.img
sudo umount /dev/mapper/cfs mnt/
sudo cryptsetup luksClose cfs
```

The task is now to copy this file to a device where I have no root permisson or without the dm_crypt kernel module (like a Windows box or a Chromebook) and get some data out of this image file, No clue if this is possible.

Is it somehow possible to decrypt the image file to get the raw ext2 fs without root/dm_crypt?

Just an idea ... no clue if something like this is possible:

- get the master key from luks header: `cryptsetup luksDump --dump-master-key fs.img`
- truncate the luks header with dd
- some other magic linux commands like gpg or openssl
- `openssl -some_magic_parameter -in fs.img -out raw_ext2.img`

Once I have the raw ext2.img I can get the data e.g. with 7z (this is the reason why I chose the old ext2 fs in this example)

- `7z x raw_ext2.img foo.txt`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you trying to create a version of the image thats unencypted and ship tjat or do you have to ship the encrypted image and decrypt it on a system tjat does not have cryptsetup?

Comment: @davidgo I've edited the question ... hopefully it's more clear now. I will decrypt a copy of the encrypted fs on an other box, where I have no dm_crypt or root permissions.

Comment: You can't truncate the raw LUKS header on the encrypted disk as step 1 and have it decryptable as the LUKS header includes the only copy of the actual encryption key.   Im not at all certain you can decrypt the block device absent the cryptsetup tool.

Comment: I can dump out the master-key from the luks header with my password `cryptsetup luksDump --dump-master-key fs.img`

Comment: Yes, but if you do that why not just decrypt the drive and if neccessary re-encrypt its contents in a way readable by other programs before shifting it?

Comment: @Gusiph It seems like you'd be better off using file-level encryption - Since you're using 7z to read ext2 anyways, why not encrypt with 7z?

Comment: Also, have you seen https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt

Comment: the idea was to send a copy of this encrypted fs to other boxes, without manual intervention. Of course I can do it on file level, but then i have to mount the FS first, and encrypt the files... but the more I investigate, the more I come to the conclusion that it's not as easy as I thought

Comment: @davidgo https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt that looks interting

Answer (score 0):

PARTIAL ANSWER

It is unlikely you can do what you are attempting in a generic way.

What you **can** do is decrypt the container on the host and then re-encrypt the block device in a way that can be opened on other systems.

```
cryptsetup luksOpen fs.img cfs
```

Creates an Unencrypted version og the block device.  Instead of mounting it, you can simply encrypt /dev/mapper/cfs in such a way that its readable on othet systems - and as an added bonus you can compress it for transfer.

I've not tried it but maybe you can use something like

```
cat /dev/mapper/cfs |  7z a archive.gz -pPASSWORD -tgzip cfs.img
```

I do wpnder if LUKS is the appropriate tool for the job - have you considered using Veracrypt - which is cross platform - instead?

Also, why ext2?  Would you not be better off with a vfat filesystem?

Comment: The idea is to automate the copy process, copy the encrytped fs to other boxes it it is not mounted without manual interaction. I didn't know veracrypt ... I will check if this works for my case. ext2 was just an example as I can extract files from ext2 via 7z, but not from ext4.

Comment: VFAT is the lowest common denominator filesystem - it works on pretty much all OS's at the expense of file permissions and some filename limits.   I also think this is an XY question (ie you are asking how do I make this tool do X, when maybe what you should be asking is How do I achieve Y).  There are lots of ways of backing up data and shifting data around systems securely.    Maybe you should ask another question "How do I achieve goals X,Y and Z, and not mention LUKS at all.